# substitution method for recurrences

Tags: algorithm, substitution, recurrence

**T(n) = 4T (36n/2) + cn2** 
Analyze the recurrence shown above, then use the substitution method to prove the following guess : **T(n) = Ɵ(n2)**

is my answer correct?

```
     T(n) <= d(36n/2) + cn²
     T(n) <= 4d(36n/2)² + cn²
     T(n) = 4d(36n²/4)
     T(n) = d36n² + cn²
     T(n) = dn² + cn²
     = dn²
```

Comment: You shouldn't bother with substituting a guess into a recurrence relation as there is no guarantee that this will correctly prove/disprove it. And anyway, this is not what the "substitution method" means.

Answer (score 0):

T(n) ≤c(36 n/2) + cn^2

T(n) ≤4c(36 n/2 )^2+cn^2

```
 T(n) = 4 c (18n)^2+cn^2
 T(n) =4 c( 324 n² )+ cn²
 T(n) =1296 cn² + cn²
 = θcn²
```

---

T(n) ≤ c(36n/2) + cn²

```
 T(n) ≤ 4c(36n/2)² + cn²
 T(n) = 4c(36n²/4)+c n²
 T(n) = c36n² + cn²
 T(n) = cn² + cn²
 = cn²
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot use the fact that `dn² + cn²= Θ(dn²)` to conclude that `T(n) = Θ(n²)` since you are using a proof by induction, you need to prove that your hypothesis is true at rank m for any m < n then it is also true at rank n, here your hypothesis is `T(m) <= cm²` which is not the same as `T(m) <= cm²+something else` so your proof by induction is not valid.